# Child controls in an ItemsControl are being disabled, but I can't figure out what's disabling them

Tags: wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol, coercion, isenabled

I'm trying to create a browser-esque tab interface in WPF. I've got it put together and it worked for a while, but now all the buttons that make the tabs function are disabled. In the live visual tree it says overidden and shows coercion setting IsEnabled = false. None the parent items are disabled.

Couple things I've tried. I tried explicitly stating that everything was enabled. This didn't help. The next thing I tried was to wipe everything out and just use a plain button. This worked, so I think the problem is somewhere in my styles.

**This Doesn't Work**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="70,15,0,0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Button Background="{x:Null}" Height="24" MinWidth="140"  Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor} }" CommandParameter="{Binding }">
                <Border MinWidth="140" Height="24" >
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                   <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsEqual}">
                                            <Binding Path=".ID"/>
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentPageViewModel.ID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LIGHT_Main_100}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DARK_CYAN_Secondary_100}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LIGHT_Main_85}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,.5,.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DARK_Faded }"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="15" Padding="0" Loaded="Label_Loaded" >
                            <Label.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Label">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Value="False">
                                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsEqual}">
                                                    <Binding Path=".ID"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentPageViewModel.ID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                             </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DARK_Faded}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Label.Style>
                                </Label>
                                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="{x:Null}" Content="&#10539;" Height="24" Width="28" FontSize="15" Padding="0,-6,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding ClosePage }" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsEqual}">
                                                            <Binding Path=".ID"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentPageViewModel.ID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

**This Does Work**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="70,15,0,0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate >
             <Button Content="Test"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

**EDIT**

This was probably what caused my issues. A while back I copied this code from an example online and didn't understand it, but it worked. I think canExecute was false because I was not sending a string parameter, but rather an object. Thanks for your help @Neil

```
public ICommand ChangePageCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_changePageCommand == null)
        {
            _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                p => ChangeViewModel((string) p),
                p => p is string);
        }

        return _changePageCommand;
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members
    public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameters)
    {
        _execute(parameters);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CanExecute for your ChangePageCommand command is probably returning false. To check simply remove the command binding and see if the button is still disabled.

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor} }"
```

Comment: Yep, you're right, taking out the command binding made the problem go away. So how do I go about figuring out why it's CanExecute would be false?

Comment: Pretty sure I found out where I was going wrong. I made an edit above if you want to look at it. Thank you for your help @Neil